# this dependency was not found: * firebase in ./src/firebase/firebase.js

Tags: vue.js

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"firebase": "^9.0.0",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-router": "^4.0.11"
   },
```

firebase.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

this line is getting error.

*This dependency was not found:

- firebase in ./src/firebase/firebase.js
  To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase*

I installed firebase but still it does not see. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

I changed like that and it worked